# show order payment option in order (admin/commerce/order)

Tags: commerce

I am using commerce kickstart (In admin/commerce/orders) How to show payment options for (authenticate) user. As, i give all the permission for authenticate role.

admin page screenshot show quick edit option Edit, invoice, payment, and delete

[image: admin page screenshot show quick edit option Edit, invoice, payment, and delete]

authenticate role page screenshot show quick edit here it is not option for any of the above.

[image: authenticate role page screenshot show quick edit here it is not option for any of the above]

Comment: Click 'edit', then the 'Payments' tab...or click the link that clearly says 'Payment' in your screenshot

Comment: payment option show in admin screenshot (click arrow) I want to show for siteadmin.

Comment: Yep, that's what I said...

Answer (score 0):

Enable permission "Use the administration pages and help" under the System section should do the trick.